# Elementos HTML ultrapassam a largura da tela

Tags: html, css, div

Como posso fazer para o componente criado respeitar a largura da tela? O que estou criando está ultrapassando os limites da tela e não consigo fazê-los respeitar esses limites.

Abaixo segue o meu código de treino.

```css
/* =============== RESET =============== */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  /* overflow-x: hidden; */
}

#profile {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21.75rem;
  /*348px*/
  height: 18.25rem;
  /*292px*/
  left: 2.5rem;
  /*40px*/
  top: 2.5rem;
  /*40px*/
  background-color: blue;
}

#links {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21.75rem;
  /*348px*/
  height: 21.75rem;
  /*348px*/
  left: 2.5rem;
  /*40px*/
  top: 22.625rem;
  /*362px*/
  background-color: blueviolet;
}

#technologies {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21.75rem;
  /*348px*/
  height: 13rem;
  /*208px*/
  left: 2.5rem;
  /*40px*/
  top: 46.25rem;
  /*740px*/
  background-color: brown;
}

#experiences {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21.75rem;
  /*348px*/
  height: 21.8125rem;
  /*349px*/
  left: 2.5rem;
  /*40px*/
  top: 61.125rem;
  /*978px*/
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

#education {
  position: absolute;
  width: 21.75rem;
  /*348px*/
  height: 22rem;
  /*352px*/
  left: 2.5rem;
  /*40px*/
  top: 84.8125rem;
  /*1357px*/
  background-color: deeppink;
}

#my-projects {
  position: absolute;
  width: 59.5rem;
  /*952px*/
  height: 5.375rem;
  /*86px*/
  left: 28rem;
  /*448px*/
  top: 2.5rem;
  /*40px*/
  background-color: green;
}

#my-projects .project1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28.8125rem;
  /*461px*/
  height: 11.625rem;
  /*186px*/
  left: 0;
  /*448px*/
  /*LEFT=0 POIS ESTÁ EM RELAÇÃO AO MY-PROJECTS*/
  top: 7.9375rem;
  /*157px*/
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

#my-projects .project2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 28.8125rem;
  /*461px*/
  height: 11.625rem;
  /*186px*/
  left: 30.6875rem;
  /*491x*/
  top: 7.9375rem;
  /*157px*/
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
}

#recent-posts {
  position: absolute;
  width: 59.5rem;
  /*952px*/
  height: 5.375rem;
  /*86px*/
  left: 28rem;
  /*448px*/
  top: 25.1875rem;
  /*403px*/
  background-color: mediumvioletred;
}

#recent-posts .post {
  position: absolute;
  width: 59.5rem;
  /*952px*/
  height: 12.5625rem;
  /*201px*/
  left: 0;
  /*LEFT=0 POIS ESTÁ EM RELAÇÃO AO PROJECT1 E PROJECT2*/
  top: 9.125rem;
  /*146px*/
  /*LEFT=0 POIS ESTÁ EM RELAÇÃO AO PROJECT1 E PROJECT2*/
  background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Estudo</title>

  <!-- STYLES -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section class="section" id="profile"></section>

    <section class="section" id="links"></section>

    <section class="section" id="technologies"></section>

    <section class="section" id="experiences"></section>

    <section class="section" id="education"></section>

    <section class="section" id="my-projects">
      <div class="project1"></div>

      <div class="project2"></div>
    </section>

    <section class="section" id="recent-posts">
      <div class="post"></div>
    </section>




  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Para prosseguir com a postagem dentro do objetivo do site é importante você [edit] a postagem e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A unidade `rem` pode ser útil para elementos de layout, porém, foi especificada para definir tamanhos de fonte (`font-size`). `1rem` equivale ao valor de `font-size` do elemento `html`. Pelo que entendi, o comportamento que você espera é que as caixas caibam dentro da viewport, então, você pode utilizar uma unidade que é relativa ao tamanho da viewport, como por exemplo:

- `1vw` Relativo a 1% da largura da viewport.
- `1vh` Relativo a 1% da altura da viewport.
- `%` Relativo ao tamanho da propriedade no elemento pai.

Se você substituir as unidades dos `width` e `height` para `%`, e definir `width: 100vw;` para o `body` para que ele ocupe a tela inteira, pode alcançar o resultado esperado.

Se o que você deseja é que os elementos 'vazem' para fora da tela, porém com a scrollbar oculta, `overflow-x: hidden;` no `body` deve resolver.

Comment: Foi exatamente isso! Segui seu conselho e troquei a width do body para 100vw e substitui as unidades de width e height para porcentagem e ficou exatamente como eu queria! Muito obrigado pela a ajuda!!

Comment: Assim como a @Denise R indicou na sua resposta, sugiro que você estude layouts Responsivos, adaptativos e fluídos.